# C# 9.0 create a record from a class

Tags: c#

I would like to initialize a record from a class.  For example, I read in a bunch of objects from a ReST call.  These objects should be immutable, so the record type would fit the bill nicely, but I want to write a bunch of code to convert them to records.

Suggestions?

Comment: You _want to write a bunch of code_? Or you **don't** want to?

Comment: *These objects should be immutable* - change the [properties to `init` ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't have write access to the API that creates the classes? Because, honestly, it would probably better just to rewrite that.

There are libraries available such as AutoMapper (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Beyond that, there are no casts you can use, and unless the classes are highly regular, you need to write custom conversions for each class.

Comment: Think I'd describe AutoMapper as a library rather than an API